# PHP how to find uppercase in array

Tags: php, uppercase, lowercase

I have an array with many words, but some senteces are in uppercase. For example:

`THIS SENTENCE IS UPPERCASE`

`this sentece is in lowercase`

And I want to split this two sentences by `\r\n`, but I cant find how to do it

Here is how I retrive this array:

```
    $result_pk_info = array();
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($sql_pk_info))
    {
        $opisanie = iconv("cp1257", "UTF-8", trim($row['opis']));
        $id = iconv("cp1257", "UTF-8", trim($row['pacientid']));
        $date = iconv("cp1257", "UTF-8", trim($row['data']));

        $desc = explode('@#$', $opisanie);

        $all_info = "<tr><td>".$desc[1]."</td></tr>";

        $result_pk_info[] = $all_info;
    }
```

in `$desc` I have words array in which I want to search and split uppercase and lowercase.

So can anyone help me with it?

**UPD** the text which I have hase something like this structure:
`SENTENCE IN UPPERCASE Sentece in lower case`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-upper.php

Comment: Are entire words upper-case or can they be part upper/part lower as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is what you're looking for :

```
    function split_upper_lower ($string)
{
    $words = explode (' ', $string);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        if (ctype_upper ($word))
            $new_string_array[++$i]['type'] = 'UPPER';  
        else
            $new_string_array[++$i]['type'] = 'LOWER';
        $new_string_array[$i]['word'] = $word;
    }
    $new_string = '';
    foreach ($new_string_array as $key => $new_word)
    {
        if (!isset ($current_mode))
        {
            if (ctype_upper ($new_word))
                $current_mode = 'UPPER';
            else
                $current_mode = 'LOWER';
        }
        if ($new_word['type'] === $current_mode)
        {
            $new_string .= $new_word['word'];
            if (isset ($new_string_array[$key + 1]))
                $new_string .= ' ';
        }
        else
        {
            $new_string .= "\r\n" . $new_word['word'];
            if (isset ($new_string_array[$key + 1]))
                $new_string .= ' ';
            if ($current_mode === 'UPPER') $current_mode = 'LOWER';
            else $current_mode = 'UPPER';
        }
    }
    return $new_string;
}
```

Tested it with `br` :

```
$string = 'HI how ARE you doing ?';
echo split_upper_lower ($string);
```

Output :

```
HI 
how 
ARE 
you doing ?
```

Comment: but if I have text like `]VAIROGDZIEDZERA 
<br>
UN VIRSPUSĒJI  
<br>
NOVIETOTO ORGĀNU US
 Vairogdziedzeris palielināts, parastas lokalizācijas, asimetrisks: labā daiva lielāka.
Labā daiva 2,6x2,0 cm.
 Kreisā daiva 2,1x2,0 cm.
  Istmus 0,4  cm .
  Kontūras  nelīdzenas.Struktūra uzskatāmi rupjgraudaina, pazeminātu ehogenitāti, ar multipliem, zemas ehogenitātes ieslēgumiem. Mezgli nevizualizējas.
`
how I need to change your code? @C. Malet

Comment: What's the problem happening with this string ? You want to add `\r\n` and not `<br>` right ?

Comment: it doesnot matter which `\r\n` or `<br>` I will use in this string, or it does?

Comment: It depends WHERE the new string will be used. In a file you'd want to use `\r\n`, for HTML display you'd want `br`

Comment: I display this string in html table

Comment: Then replace `\r\b` with `<br>` in my code, isn't it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
$string = 'THIS SENTENCE IS UPPERCASE';
$string2 = 'this sentece is in lowercase';

if(preg_match ( '/[A-Z ]$/' , $string))
{
echo 'uppercase';
}
else
{
echo 'lowercase';
}
```

Use this in your loop through $desc. Where $string is one element of an array containing one string.

/[A-Z ]$/ will match all uppercase with spaces. You can just upgrade your regexp to grab something else from strings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you can do like this ...

```
$desc = array ("abcd","ABCD","bbb","B");

foreach($desc as $value) {

     if(ctype_upper($value)) {
      // character is upper
     } else {

      // character is lower

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `preg_match_all()`. Use the following code,

```
$result_pk_info = array();
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($sql_pk_info))
    {
        $opisanie = iconv("cp1257", "UTF-8", trim($row['opis']));
        $id = iconv("cp1257", "UTF-8", trim($row['pacientid']));
        $date = iconv("cp1257", "UTF-8", trim($row['data']));

        $desc = explode('@#$', $opisanie);
        //converting $desc array to string 
$string = implode(" " , $desc);
//Upper case Matching
$upprCase = preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/', $string, $uprmatches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

if($upprCase){
foreach ($uprmatches as $match)
{
    foreach($match as $value)
    //Iam a uppercase
    print $UpperCase = $value[0];
}}

//Splitting with \r\n
print "\r\n";

//lower case matching
$lowrCase = preg_match_all('/[a-z]/', $string, $lowrmatches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
if($lowrCase){
    foreach ($lowrmatches as $match)
    {
        foreach($match as $value)
            //Iam a lowercase
            print $lowerCase = $value[0];
    }}
}
```